# Database mirroring and replication on SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, replication, mirror

How can I configure my mirror database to publish its data to the same replication database that my primary has ( I need to take my primary database offline for maintenance purposes.)?

Answer (score 1):

See: [Replication and Database Mirroring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151799.aspx) for the details on how to set this up.